# Using CustomValidationAttribute with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to implement some conditional validation logic on one of my entities. Basically, what I want to do is validate a field (using a regular expression) only if another field in my entity has a certain value.

I tried adding a `CustomValidationAttribute` on my entity but it doesn't do anything

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TemplateActionMetadata))]
[CustomValidation(typeof(TemplateAction), "validateActionValue")]
    public partial class TemplateAction 
    {
        public static ValidationResult validateActionValue(string pValue, ValidationContext vContext)
        { //this never gets called
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

I also tried adding the attribute on my field

```
public partial class TemplateActionMetadata
    {

        [CustomValidation(typeof(TemplateAction), "validateActionValue")]
        public string ActionValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Now it does call the `validateActionValue` method but the `ValidationContext` parameter is always null, so I have no way of getting the value of the other field that I need to use to implement my validation logic.

Answer (score 0):

In the msdn documentation, i can see that the CustomValidationAttribute class has a readonly RequiresValidationContext property.

This property is overridden from the base class ValidationAttribute.

Since you don't have the context, i suppose this property return false, by design.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.aspx

So you can't get the context with this attribute.
You may have to create yourself a custom attribute which fulfill your needs

I found this Microsoft Guideline which could help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488527.aspx